# Extensions for "Invisible" Parts of Functions

Tags: complex-numbers, approximation, regression, curves

My graphing calculator won't graph functions like
$$f(x)=(-2)^x$$
which I assume is because it exists in $\mathbb R$ only sporadically for fractional $x$ and because it fluctuates so quickly from integer to integer. However, so that I can graph a function like this, I've devised a way to graph its points for integer values of $x$. If I factor out the $-1$, I get
$$f(x)=(-1)^x2^x$$
and, for integer values of $x$, $(-1)^x$ has the same values as $\cos \pi x$, so I let
$$f_\approx(x)=2^x\cos\pi x$$
And it works! I can see the real values of my original function for all integer values of $x$. I can use this same method for other functions, like $$g(x)=x^x$$
That sometimes do not exist and become sporadic because some values of $x$ result in negative bases with fractional exponents. My extension of this function is
  $$ g_\approx(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       x^x & : x \ge 0\\
       (-x)^x \cos \pi x & : x \lt 0
     \end{array}
   \right.\\
$$
My question is this: my extensions accurately represent the values of $f$ and $g$ for $x \in \mathbb Z$, but for the values of $f$ and $g$ that do not exist, do $f_\approx$ and $g_\approx$ mean anything? Do they have any relationship with the complex values generated by $f$ and $g$ for those values of $x$?

Comment: The function $(-1)^x$ for fractional $x$ can be understood in the context of complex numbers, as $(-1)^x = e^{i\pi x} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$. But it is multivalued, in the sense that it depends on a choice of $\log(-1)$ which could be among $i\pi + 2k\pi i, k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Typo: $e^{i\pi x} = \cos(\pi x) + i \sin(\pi x)$.

Comment: These are good questions.  I think to give a general answer of the 'right' way to extend functions, you need to delve into complex analysis and [analytic continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation).  Roughly, if the functions are expandable in power series (analytic) then there are 'correct' ways of extending the function to preserve the property of analyticity - but in the presence of singularities there may be more than one choice, depending on a branch cut.

Comment: @Frpzzd : Use a software made to plot complex function, for example :  http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%28-2%29%5Ex&x=0&y=0